# How to import autoitlibray into ride?

Tags: python, robotframework, autoit

I tried to import autoitlibrary into Ride GUI but it failed with the below error.

```
"20200316 17:23:25.335 [WARN]: Importing test library "C:\Users\user\AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/RobotFramework/Extensions/AutoItLibrary/" failed

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\robotide\spec\librarymanager.py", line 86, in _fetch_keywords
    library_name.replace('/', os.sep), os.path.abspath('.'))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\robotide\spec\xmlreaders.py", line 99, in get_path
    return _resolve_path(name.replace('/', os.sep), basedir)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\robotide\spec\xmlreaders.py", line 116, in _resolve_path
    raise robotapi.DataError"
```

Anything which am not doing it right??

Comment: That error message is not from RIDE, but from `robot`. Are you importing the correct AutoItLibrary? Is it compatible with Python 3?

Comment: @helio, yes it is compatible with python 3, autoit was installed using PIP

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I installed `robotframework-autoitlibrary` in Python 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

Following the installation instructions on AutoItLibrary's project [Readme](https://github.com/nokia/robotframework-autoitlibrary/blob/master/ReadMe.md), I found no problems. Special attention is the **administrative privilege command**. The version is 1.2.5 (which may be newer than the date of the question).

Screenshot of simple example with RIDE 2.0b1.dev0 (current development version):
[image: Example of AutoITLibrary test suite, with RIDE 2.0b1.dev0 (current development version)]